# appcompat Error in Gradle

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-appcompat

I used android studio version 3.0.1 and my version gradle is 3.0.1. I created a new project with map activity but when the gradle is sync, i get below errors:

```
Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2.
Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2.
Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2.
Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@release/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2.
Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@releaseUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2.
```

I removed all of packages about test application but again i see debugUnitTest in my error. why after remove, show this error?

my internet is slow and i used vpn proxy and set port and ip of proxy in android studio settings.

my Module: app gradle is:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 27
buildToolsVersion '27.0.2'
defaultConfig {
    applicationId ""
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 27
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.0.4'

}
```

what is my problem and how can i fix this?
thanks

Comment: do you enabled offline build?

Comment: Please find in the sdk manager that buildToolsVersion '27.0.2' is available or not, If available then remove it and install it again. Also as suggested by @Rajasekaran check that offline mode is checked or not....

Comment: I enabled offline build but again i have same errors. why?